# Which approach to take when using jqgrid with webapi, Entity Framework 5 and ASPNET MVC 4

Tags: entity-framework, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm working on a project which uses jqgrid with webapi, Entity Framework 5 and ASPNET MVC 4.
WebApi controllers are working OK and I can make CRUD operations from tests.

Now, I'm developing the UI with jqgrid. My problem comes for example with one to many relationships.

I have this two entities:

```
public class Door
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int HouseId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public House House { get; set; }
}
```

and this one

```
public class House
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Door> Doors { get; set; }
}
```

my jqgrid colmode code in the jqgrid is this one:

```
colModel: [
{ name: 'Id', index: 'id', editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, align: 'left' },
{ name: 'Description', index: 'description', editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, align: 'left' },
{
name: 'HouseId', index: 'HouseId', editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: false, align: 'left',
edittype: "select", editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: {
        dataUrl: $("#ServiceUrlHouse").val(),
        buildSelect: function (data) {
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            var html = '<select>';
            if (response && response.length) {
                for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l ; i++) {
                    var item = response[i];
                    html += '<option value="' + item.Id + '">' + item.Name + '</option>';
                }
            }
            return html + "</select>";
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I want to show the House name when the grid is in view mode and have the select (combo) when in edit mode, and then send back to WebApi the Original Door to be updated in the database.

**Note 1:** If I don't put [JsonIgnore] I get self referencing loop

**Note 2** I though of creating a DTO like this one:

```
public class DoorDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int HouseId { get; set; }
        public string HouseName { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is that I need to modify the jqgrid part code and change HouseId column name with HouseName, (If I do it, I can see the name of the House in view mode => that's ok). BUT, when I edit any record, the json that returns to webapi doesn't send a Door object, it sends a DoorDto, then the update by Entity Framework 5 fails.

I know I can create another method that received a DoorDto, but it would be dirty. Is there any best way to handle this?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.